# MVC 4 Entity Framework 5 cant delete many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 and MVC 4 code first approach. I am very new to both of these so I might have made an simple error I am trying to delete a many to many relationship from the database. I can add the relationship fine but when I want to remove it I get an error.

I have to tables with a many to many relationship. I have Employee class and deduction class:

Employee class linked to Deduction class by ICollection:

```
public class Employee
{

    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int CellNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public int BankAccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string PayInterval { get; set; }
    public double NormalRate { get; set; }
    public double OvertimeRate { get; set; }
    public double SetHours { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfEmployment { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastPaymentRecieved { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
    public int JobID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Holiday> holiday { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bonus> bonus { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Absent> absent { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Deduction> Deductions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<HoursWorked> HoursWorke { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Payroll> Payrolls { get; set; }
}
```

Deduction class linked to Employee class by ICollection:

```
public class Deduction
{

    public int DeductionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Payroll> Payroll { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my current code for removing:

```
    public void RemoveEmployeeDeduction(int empID, int dedID)
    {
        var employee = db.Employee.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == empID);

        var ded = db.Deduction.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeductionID == dedID);

        employee.Deductions.Remove(ded);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

I did check both the employee and the deduction I want to remove is fetched correctly. I have noticed that at employee.Deductions.Remove(ded) the Deductions is null. 
Here is the error:

[Code](http://i57.tinypic.com/zk49jp.png)

I have also tried multiple answers on stack overflow but none seems to work so maybe an example with my code would help me.

Thanks in advance.

Edit

I have resolved this error by adding the following:
The problem was that I did not include the the Deductions when retrieving the the employee. It is now working as expected.

```
    public void RemoveEmployeeDeduction(int empID, int dedID)
    {
        var employee = db.Employee.Include("Deductions").FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmployeeID == empID);

        var ded = db.Deduction.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeductionID == dedID);

        employee.Deductions.Remove(ded);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code and error in your post (use the code fprmat). Links & external images can become broken so it is frowned upon.

Comment: I assume that you also initialised your collections before trying to call `Remove()`.

Comment: @TomToms Thanks for the advice I have changed my post.

Comment: @AgentShark Yes that seemed to have been my problem I resolved it by adding .Include(). Thanks for the quick reply.